# nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61' while CUDA 8.0 is installed

Tags: c++, cuda, nvcc, luarocks

I have a problem while installing cutorch with luarocks. The error announces that gpu architecture 'compute_61' is not supported. After some search I figured out that the problem can be caused by old CUDA version. But it is not the case since I have CUDA 8.0

```
sudo ~/torch/install/bin/luarocks install cutorch
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cutorch-scm-1.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cutorch-scm-1.rockspec... switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'cutorch'...
remote: Counting objects: 220, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (174/174), done.
remote: Total 220 (delta 60), reused 93 (delta 44), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (220/220), 211.56 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (60/60), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/anya/torch/install/bin/.." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/anya/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/cutorch/scm-1" && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) install

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Torch7 in /home/anya/torch/install
-- Found CUDA: /usr (found suitable version "7.5", minimum required is "6.5") 
-- TH_LIBRARIES: TH
-- Found gcc >=5 and CUDA <= 7.5, adding workaround C++ flags
-- MAGMA not found. Compiling without MAGMA support
-- Autodetected CUDA architecture(s): 6.1
-- got cuda version 7.5
-- Found CUDA with FP16 support, compiling with torch.CudaHalfTensor
-- CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS: -gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1
-- THC_SO_VERSION: 0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensor.cu.o
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o
[  3%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o
[  5%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o
[  5%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o
[  6%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCStorage.cu.o
[  7%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCStorageCopy.cu.o
[  9%] Building NVCC (Device) object lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensor.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCTensor.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensor.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensor.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o


nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o] Error 1
lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o] Error 1
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCStorageCopy.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCStorageCopy.cu.o


CMake Error at THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:91: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCStorageCopy.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCStorageCopy.cu.o] Error 1
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:70: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o] Error 1
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:546: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o] Error 1
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_61'
CMake Error at THC_generated_THCStorage.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCStorage.cu.o


CMake Error at THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /tmp/luarocks_cutorch-scm-1-201/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCStorage.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCStorage.cu.o] Error 1
lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:105: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCTensorCopy.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:172: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

I have CUDA 8.0 version and GTX1070 gpu

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

and nvidia-367 driver

```
nvidia-smi
Tue Jan 17 14:04:47 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P5    11W /  N/A |    209MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       997    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             164MiB |
|    0      1855    G   compiz                                          42MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: The cmake output hints at a Cuda 7.5 install still on your machine. You can try to update it, or edit the Makefile to use Cuda 8.0 or even edit the environment variable pointing to cuda 7.5 (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

In cmake checks at the beginning of installing cutorch you have:

`-- Found CUDA: /usr (found suitable version "7.5", minimum required is "6.5")`

It looks like you have two CUDA versions installed -and  `7.5` is picked by the installer. Another option is that installer doesn't support `8.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everybody who replied. Finally the problem was resolved by reinstalling Torch AND (what I guess might be the reason) updating cudnn (from version V4 to V5).

Comment: Please list the versions involved.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar (`compute 70`). I think it was because I upgraded my ubuntu distribution (16.04 --> 18.04) and cuda 8.0 is not supported for ubuntu 18.04. I uninstalled cuda 8.0, installed cuda 10.1, and the problem seems to have gone away.

Caveat: I was trying to solve the problem a few different ways, and this was the last thing I tried before it worked. Technically it could have been one of the intermediate steps that solved the `unsupported gpu architecture` error, but I can't go back and check now.